# How to append the return value to single complex variable from 3 threads in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I am calling 3 different functions in 3 threads and I need to append the all the return values from 3 threads.

what I tried was

```
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() => response.Candidate = AddCandidate2Daxtra(request, args));
    t1.Start();

    Thread t2 = new Thread(() => response.Candidate.HRXML = parsecv(profile));
    t2.Start();

    Thread t3 = new Thread(() => response.Candidate.Attachments.Add(Print2Flash(alias, bytes, args)));
    t3.Start();

    while (t1.IsAlive == true || t2.IsAlive == true || t3.IsAlive == true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

but finally I'm getting first thread value only.I'm not getting the remaining two threads values.
So any one please help me what is the problem?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: just to note you don't need all the `== true` you have

Comment: can you use `Task<T>` from .net 4.x?

Comment: @Lax_me have a look here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: you should go with background workers. they can update properties without need of lock and you can customize every complete work. it make it much more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a race condition because you don't know the order in which the threads will finish.

Use a separate local variable for each thread, which you assign inside the thread constructor similar to how you do just now with `response`.

Then wait for all the threads using `.Join()`:

```
t1.Join();
t2.Join();
t3.Join();
```

Then use the local variables to set `response` after all the `Join()` calls have returned.

However, I'd use Tasks instead. Here's an example. It runs in separate threads three different methods each of which has a different return type:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            // Using tasks directly:

            var task1 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(methodOne);
            var task2 = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(methodTwo);
            var task3 = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(methodThree);

            // Alternatively:
            // var task1 = Task.Run(new Func<int>(methodOne));
            // var task2 = Task.Run(new Func<string>(methodTwo));
            // var task3 = Task.Run(new Func<double>(methodThree)); 

            string result = string.Format
            (
                "Task 1: {0}, Task 2: {1}, Task 3: {2}",
                task1.Result, // Accessing Task.Result automatically
                task2.Result, // waits for the task to complete.
                task3.Result 
            );

            Console.WriteLine(result);

            // Alternatively, you can use tasks indirectly via Parallel.Invoke().
            // You might find this more readable and less typing:

            int    r1 = 0;
            string r2 = null;
            double r3 = 0;

            Parallel.Invoke
            (
                () => r1 = methodOne(),
                () => r2 = methodTwo(),
                () => r3 = methodThree()
            );

            result = string.Format
            (
                "Task 1: {0}, Task 2: {1}, Task 3: {2}",
                r1,
                r2,
                r3
            );

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        static int methodOne()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return 1;
        }

        static string methodTwo()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(750);
            return "two";
        }

        static double methodThree()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            return 3.0;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Whichever approach you take, the important thing is that you should not assign the results directly to `response` inside the thread or task - wait until all the threads or tasks have finished and only then assign the results to `response`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the thread `t1` is scheduled after `t2` and `t3`. You can rewrite your code like this:

```
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() => response.Candidate = AddCandidate2Daxtra(request, args));
    t1.Start();
    t1.Join();

    Thread t2 = new Thread(() => response.Candidate.HRXML = parsecv(profile));
    t2.Start();

    Thread t3 = new Thread(() => response.Candidate.Attachments.Add(Print2Flash(alias, bytes, args)));
    t3.Start();

    while (/*t1.IsAlive == true || */t2.IsAlive == true || t3.IsAlive == true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
// get all the data you need separately
Candidate candidate = null; // no idea of the real type

Thread t1 = new Thread(() => candidate = AddCandidate2Daxtra(request, args));
t1.Start();

HRXML HRXML = null; // no idea of the real type

Thread t2 = new Thread(() => HRXML = parsecv(profile));
t2.Start();

Attachment att = null; // no idea of the real type

Thread t3 = new Thread(() => att = Print2Flash(alias, bytes, args));
t3.Start();

while (t1.IsAlive || t2.IsAlive || t3.IsAlive)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

And when all is done:

```
response.Candidate = candidate;
candidate.HRXML = HRXML;
response.Candidate.Attachments.Add(att);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that `t2` and `t3` are dependent on `t1` completing. If `t2` and `t3` finish before `t1` then their results will be injected into the older instance of `Candidate`. You need to break this dependency.

Consider the following code.

```
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => parsecv(profile));
var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Print2Flash(alias, bytes, args));
response.Candidate = AddCandidate2Daxtra(request, args);
response.Candidate.HRXML = t2.Result;
response.Candidate.Attachments.Add(t3.Result);
```

What we are doing here is launching `t2` and `t3` asynchronously and when they are complete their return values will be stored in the `Task` instances that are created. In the meantime, what was originally `t1` will now be executed synchronously on the main thread. There is no point in creating a new thread to do this work. Just have the main the thread do it because otherwise it would be sitting their idle anyway. Once `AddCandidate2Daxtra` is complete then its constituent values can be retrieved from `Task.Result` and assigned. The `Task.Result` property blocks until the task completes.

There are various other ways to do this, but most will not be as elegant and easy to read as the above. If `Task` is not available to you then let me know in the comments and I will update my answer to include a non-TPL friendly method.